# How to prevent others from using my facebook application?

Tags: facebook

I just created a Facebook application that basically creates a new Tab on my Facebook-profile-page and loads contents from my website in an inline frame. Now I got to the point that I added the application to my profile page with a simple link like http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=APP_ID&pages=1. But how can I prevent others from just doing the same and using my app on their pages then?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Great question.  Upvoting it for you. What have you tried so far to limit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!  You know the page that it is supposed to belong to, so hard code that in your app's code and you can check the page id coming in from the signed_request and see if that page id is yours.  If not, send down not permitted in your response HTML. If it is your page, then response down the good HTML.  :)

For more information on signed_request see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/